# Can typescript automatically detect type of an array?

Tags: typescript

I frequently run into this pattern:

```
function f() : VeryLongOrComplexType[] {
   const arr : VeryLongOrComplexType[] = []
   for (...) {
      ...
      arr.push(...)
   }
   return arr;
}
```

My focus is on

```
const arr : VeryLongOrComplexType[] = []
```

If I don't specify a type, it assumes `arr`'s type is `never[]` and gives me an error at  `arr.push(...)`

But I also feel like that `arr`'s type could be inferred from either the `.push` or from the return type, but it's not.

Is any configuration through which I could just omit type declaration at the time of array declaration? e.g. `const arr = []` instead of `const arr : VeryLongOrComplexType[] = []`?

Here's [a reproduction of the issue](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false&ts=4.2.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGrQJ4BkD2IDmA8lAMI4C2ADgDYQAeAKhpSgN7JwBcyAzmFKHzIAvgCgEePrwoQwAC0HcAFHWTcQAV3IAjaAEpkAXgB8yAApQKwHhAA82nDlpwQpw8k3VqAQnGSw0uQQWNZg6lq6UADaALpGHhpevqJwPBggCMgwGhlgwHhZSgbcFlY2tuhQ2HhEpBQ09EwssaasosjIEiBScFBQ8bHtWTj9Sl1SqjgwgcGhBm0dHcDTSnAA7nDAATwy8oIqevNDi53+yABuCGFomLgExGRUtIzMKO6ePseLvVAAdJQaHhyJSXMB6L5iDqQ5BQWQaKAgDh9ADcojEAHp0Vkcld8oiYEVuJUMA96s8mhBYkA) as prompted by the comments. I suspect it has something to do with `noImplicitAny` configuration.

[image: a screenshot of about ts playground link]

Comment: [I can't reproduce your issue](https://tsplay.dev/mpDyzm).  Perhaps you could provide a [mre] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE that demonstrates the problem you're seeing?  Otherwise you might not get a helpful answer.

Comment: I tried re-producing it in the playground. I added some complexity to your minimal example, but it seems that it has something to do with `noImplicitAny` configuration and apart from that maybe everything else is fine. I still don't understand what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass as an argument an element which you want a push to `arr`:

```js
function f<T>(elem: T): T[] {
  const arr: T[] = []
  arr.push(elem)
  return arr;
}
```

There is no other approach to infer `arr` type from `push` because `push` is already used on `arr` so it need to know the type.

Since you are iterating over some data structure I think it worth using `reduce` or `map` here:

```js
const obj = {
  age: 42,
  name: 'John'
}

const f = () =>
  Object.keys(obj)
    .reduce<string[]>((acc, elem) => [...acc, elem], [])
```

As you might have noticed, you still need to explicitly type `string[]` because TS always infers empty array as a `never[]`.

If you provide reproducible example I think you will get more meaningful answer.

**UPDATE**

In this example:

```js
interface VeryLongOrComplexType { a: string }
const something: (x: number) => Promise<boolean> = null!
const someList: number[] = null!

async function f(): Promise<VeryLongOrComplexType[]> {
  const arr = []
  for (const x of someList) {
    if (await something(x)) {
      const vct: VeryLongOrComplexType = null as any as VeryLongOrComplexType;
      arr.push(vct)
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
```

**`arr`** - can't be infered neither from return type nor from `push`

In order to do that, you should make `arr` a variable instead of `constant`, like here:

```js
interface VeryLongOrComplexType { a: string }
const something: (x: number) => Promise<boolean> = null!
const someList: number[] = null!

async function f(){
  let arr;
  arr = []
  for (const x of someList) {
    if (await something(x)) {
      const vct: VeryLongOrComplexType = null as any as VeryLongOrComplexType;
      arr.push(vct)
      arr // VeryLongOrComplexType[]
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
```

If you hover on `f`, you will see that return type is `Promise<VeryLongOrComplexType[]>`. Just like you expect.

Credits goes to `@jcalz`.

However, I don't think that you should do such thinkgs in your production code. I still think it is better to explicitly type your empty array, like here:

```js
const arr: VeryLongOrComplexType[] = [];
```

Comment: There are auto-typed arrays in TypeScript https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#improved-any-inference

Comment: Thanks. This can save some keystrokes but it introduces the parameter in function type which isn't really required, and I suspect that may work in some cases but in some others it could make the code less readable. I'll wait to see if there's a better way. I've updated the question with a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha your exmaple is still not reproducible

Comment: @captain-yossarian how do you mean? I've added a screenshot to the question of what I see when I visit the typescript playground link, look at the error underline and the error message on the right

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha my bad, I hsould have refresh a page

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha made an update